# Одинаковые таблицы в бд

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеются несколько таблиц с категориями и товарами. У некоторых категорий одинаковые имена, возможно ли как-то средствами mysql слить эти две таблицы в одну? Слить по имени

Comment: одинаковые имена категорий не гарантируют что остальные признаки тоже одинаковы, это к тому, что вопрос неполный - добавьте описание структуры данных этих таблиц, добавьте подробное описание того, что требуется получить

Comment: Если категории не являются ключами таблицы и таблицы идентичны по своей структуре, что Вам мешает слить данные в одну таблицу? Как максимум задайте идентификатор таблицы к которой он принадлежал ранее.